# 503 error in hosting a node.js dynamic website on cyclic.sh

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hosting, cyclic

I am getting 503 error , while trying to host my website on cyclic.sh.
There is connection to the mongodb atlas for database.
When I run the webapp on my localhost, it works fine. But each time I deploy the web application on cyclic.sh I receive 503 error. The app.js file is provided below.

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const csrf = require("csurf");
const expressSession = require("express-session");

const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth.routes");
const db = require("./database/database");
const addCsrfTokenMiddleware = require("./middlewares/csrf-tokens");
const errorHandlerMiddleware = require("./middlewares/error-handler");
const createSessionConfig = require("./config/session");
const productsRoutes = require("./routes/products.routes");
const baseRoutes = require("./routes/base.routes");
const checkAuthStatusMiddleware = require("./middlewares/check-auth");
const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin.routes");
const protectRoutes = require("./middlewares/protect-routes");
const cartMiddleware = require("./middlewares/cart");
const cartRoutes = require("./routes/cart.routes");
const ordersRoutes = require("./routes/orders.routes");
const updateCartPrices = require("./middlewares/update-cart-prices");
const notFoundMiddleware = require("./middlewares/not-found");
const app = express();

const sessionConfig = createSessionConfig();

app.set("view engine", "ejs"); //set veiw engine as ejs
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views")); //make contents of view folder aviable public. Now they can be accessed in rotuers->controllers

app.use(express.static("public")); //make public folder accessible
app.use("/products/assets", express.static("product-data"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //send data from ejs-froms to backend
app.use(express.json()); // for sending json data to backend, fetch in cart

app.use(expressSession(sessionConfig)); //  created session after csrf and csrf is dependent on session
app.use(csrf());
app.use(cartMiddleware); //creating the cart
app.use(updateCartPrices);
app.use(addCsrfTokenMiddleware);
app.use(checkAuthStatusMiddleware);
app.use(baseRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(productsRoutes);
app.use("/cart", cartRoutes);
// app.use(protectRoutes);
app.use("/orders", protectRoutes, ordersRoutes); //only to auth users
app.use("/admin", protectRoutes, adminRoutes);
app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware); //makes the task easy for error indentification

db.connectToDatabase()
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Failed to connect to database!");
    console.log(error);
  });
```

The code of database.js  is

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
let mongodbUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017"; //default database server

if (process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
   MONGODB_URL : refers to server which hosts  your database. IF not exists then deault get used
   mongodbUrl = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
 }


let database;

async function connectToDatabase() {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(mongodbUrl);
  database = client.db("online-shop");
}

function getDb() {
  if (!database) {
    throw new Error("Database not connected");
  }
  return database;
}

module.exports = {
  connectToDatabase: connectToDatabase,
  getDb: getDb,
};
```

The value for MONGODB_URL which points to database stored in mongodb atlas is being provided by me  as:
MONGODB_URL=mongodb+srv://user_name:my_password@cluster0.lfsfoxew.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

user_name = myusername
my_password = password for the user.

I am getting 503 error in the console of browser stating : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()

Please anyone resolve it.

I tried to publish a dynamic website on cyclic.sh, but received 503 error

Answer (score 0):

## Have you added 0.0.0.0/0 to your IP Access List in Network Access controls of your project in Atlas ?

Atlas only allows connections from specific IP addresses which are mentioned in the Network Access list. When you run the project locally, the IP address you run it from gets added to the IP Access List automatically so you don't face an issue. But after deployment, you need to have 0.0.0.0/0 in your IP Access List for the server to access the Atlas DB

[image: Example IP Access List]